# ¿Cómo parar llamadas a función setInterval()?

Tags: javascript

En una página tengo varias cuentas atrás y cuando llegan a cero quiero que la función pare, pero no lo consigo.

Éste es el código:

```js
 var a=[];
 var b={};
 for(var i=3;i<6;i++)
 {
  b = {segundos: (i+1), elemento: 'demo' + (i+1)};
  a.push(b);
 }

 function mifun(X)
 {
  if(X.segundos>0) 
  {
   document.getElementById(X.elemento).innerHTML = X.segundos;
   X.segundos--;
  }
  else 
  {
   document.getElementById(X.elemento).innerHTML = "Cuenta finalizada";
   clearInterval(stop);
  }
 }
  
   for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++) 
 {
  (function(i) 
  {
   var stop = setInterval(function(){mifun(a[i]);}, 1000);
  })(i);
 }
```

```html
<span id=demo4></span><br>
<span id=demo5></span><br>
<span id=demo6></span><br>
```

Funciona, pero después de mostrar en pantalla el mensaje **Cuenta finalizada**, ese mensaje lo sigue pintando una y otra vez de manera indefinida.

Si la siguiente línea la saco del bucle `for`:

```
var stop = setInterval(function(){mifun(a[0]);}, 1000);
```

Y hago una prueba con el elemento cero del array, entonces sí se para la función `setinterval()`, pero necesito que esté dentro de un `for`, ya que las cuentas atrás podrán variar y ser más o menos.

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que cesen las llamadas a la función?

---

De esta manera no tengo que guardar el valor devuelto por setInterval()

Este código funciona correctamente para mostrar la primera cuenta atrás

```js
 var a = [];
 var b = {segundos: 5, elemento: 'demo1'};
 a.push(b);
 b = {segundos: 7, elemento: 'demo2'};
 a.push(b);

 var i=0;
 function MiFuncionJS()
 {
  if(a[i].segundos>0)
  {
   document.getElementById(a[i].elemento).innerHTML = a[i].segundos;
   a[i].segundos--;
   setTimeout("MiFuncionJS()", 1000);
  }
  else
   document.getElementById(a[i].elemento).innerHTML = "Cuenta finalizada";
 }
 MiFuncionJS();
```

```html
<span id="demo1"></span><br>
<span id="demo2"></span><br>
```

La cuenta atrás funciona y no se llama más a MiFuncionJS() cuando termina la cuenta

Pero cuando quiero mostrar varias cuentas me falla, a continuación pongo el código

```js
 var a = [];
 var b = {segundos: 5, elemento: 'demo1'};
 a.push(b);
 b = {segundos: 7, elemento: 'demo2'};
 a.push(b);

for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++)
 {
  (function(i)
  {
   function MiFuncionJS()
   {
    if(a[i].segundos>0)
    {
     document.getElementById(a[i].elemento).innerHTML = a[i].segundos;
     a[i].segundos--;
     setTimeout("MiFuncionJS()", 1000);
    }
    else
     document.getElementById(a[i].elemento).innerHTML = "Cuenta finalizada";
   }
   MiFuncionJS();
  })(i);
 }
```

```html
<span id="demo1"></span><br>
<span id="demo2"></span><br>
```

Sólo muestra una vez los datos...

Comment: Tienes un lio de funciones enorme ahi montado, generas un intervalo distinto para cada interacción de tu for, la variable stop es inaccesible cuando llamas a clearInterval. Te recomiendo que rehagas tu código de manera más organizada y declares una única vez el setInterval ya que lo que hagas dentro se va a ejecutar indefinidamente hasta que llames al clearInterval

Comment: He agregado una nueva edición a mi respuesta manteniendo tu código pero almacenando el resultado de `setInterval` en un lugar donde tu función puede tener acceso posteriormente.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En tu código estás sobreescribiendo el valor de la variable `stop` con la salida de `setInterval()` una y otra vez, por lo que al finalizar el bucle `stop` mantendrá el último valor y se habrán perdido los anteriores, por lo que los `clearInterval(stop);` pararán siempre el último contador.

Necesitas las siguientes modificaciones en tu código para mantener el valor devuelto de cada llamada a `setInterval()` y poder usarlo en la llamada a tu función:

```js
var a = [];
var b = {};

for(var i = 3; i < 6; i++) {
  b = { segundos: (i + 1), elemento: 'demo' + (i + 1) };
  a.push(b);
}

function mifun(X) {
  if (X.segundos > 0) {
    document.getElementById(X.elemento).innerHTML = X.segundos--;
  } else {
    document.getElementById(X.elemento).innerHTML = "Cuenta finalizada";
    /* Acceso a la propiedad "stop" del elemento recibido */
    clearInterval(X.stop);
    console.log('Parado:', X);
  }
}

for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  (function(i) {
    /* Guardo la salida en la matriz bajo la propiedad "stop" */
    a[i].stop = setInterval(function() { mifun(a[i]); }, 1000);
  })(i);
}
```

```html
<span id=demo4></span><br>
<span id=demo5></span><br>
<span id=demo6></span><br>
```

Te recomiendo la siguiente manera para solucionar tu problema elegantemente manteniendo la cuenta atrás en los propios [atributos de datos](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/HTML/como/Usando_atributos_de_datos) del elemento `<span>`:

```js
/* Obtenemos los elementos a temporizar */
let elementos = document.querySelectorAll('span[id^=demo]');

/* Por cada elemento creamos el temporizador asociado que
  permanecerá dentro del ámbito de la función por cada iteración */
elementos.forEach(function (elemento) {
  console.log("Configurando id/segundos:", elemento.id, elemento.dataset.segundos);
  /* Ponemos en su interior el valor inicial */
  elemento.innerText = elemento.dataset.segundos;
  /* Creamos el contador */
  var contador = setInterval(function () {
    /* Comprobamos el estado de la cuenta atrás */
    if (elemento.dataset.segundos > 1) {
      /* Decrementamos el contador */
      elemento.dataset.segundos--;
      /* Mostramos el estado del contador */
      elemento.innerText = elemento.dataset.segundos;
    } else {
      elemento.innerText = 'Cuenta finalizada';
      console.log('Finalizado el contador:', elemento.id);
      /* Paramos el temporizador */
      clearInterval(contador);
    }
  }, 1000);
});
```

```html
<span id="demo4" data-segundos="4"></span><br/>
<span id="demo5" data-segundos="5"></span><br/>
<span id="demo6" data-segundos="6"></span><br/>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! La primera manera que me ofreciste es más clara que la mía pero lo he modificado un poco para que se parezca más a mi código y me ha quedado más parecido a la segunda manera que has propuesto. Muy interesante el tema de los atributos de datos, también lo de guardar la salida en la matriz, le estuve dando vueltas pero no me salía porque me faltó añadirle la clausura... Gracias fenómeno!

Comment: Encontré otra forma en la que no hace falta almacenar el valor devuelto por la función setInterval(), pero algo me falla cuando quiero mostrar más de una cuenta atrás...

Comment: `setTimeout()` tiene el problema de no ser tan preciso con el paso del tiempo como `setInterval()`. Además, cuando pasas como cadena una función, ésta será interpretada cuando se agote el tiempo, no cuando usas `setTimeout()`. Abre una pregunta nueva para no alejarnos del tema de ésta y te ayudo allí.

Comment: @Juaqui , avísame cuando crees la nueva pregunta y recuerda que publicar respuestas que no solucionan una pregunta, si no que son preguntas nuevas, va en contra de las normas de la comunidad y podrían votarte negativamente (alguien ya lo ha hecho) y [también es muy probable que la borren](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers). Te recomiendo borrar esa respuesta y, como te dije en el comentario anterior, publicar una nueva pregunta con la nueva duda.

Comment: Ya la he publicado. Se titula ¿Cómo mostrar varias cuentas atrás con setTimeout()?. Graciasss

Answer (score 1):

Así es como también lo resolví...

```js
 var a=[];
 var b={};
 for(var i=3;i<6;i++)
 {
  b = {segundos: (i+1), elemento: 'demo' + (i+1)};
  a.push(b);
 }
  
   for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++)
 {
  (function(i)
  {
   var stop = setInterval(function()
   {
    if(a[i].segundos>0)
    {
     document.getElementById(a[i].elemento).innerHTML = a[i].segundos;
     a[i].segundos--;
    }
    else
    {
     document.getElementById(a[i].elemento).innerHTML = "Cuenta finalizada";
     clearInterval(stop);
    }
   }, 1000);
  })(i);
 }
```

```html
<span id=demo4></span><br>
<span id=demo5></span><br>
<span id=demo6></span><br>
```

O usando forEach en lugar del for...

```js
 var a=[];
 var b={};
 for(var i=3;i<6;i++)
 {
  b = {segundos: (i+1), elemento: 'demo' + (i+1)};
  a.push(b);
 }
  
  a.forEach(function(elemento)
 {
  var contador = setInterval(function()
  {
   if(elemento.segundos>0)
   {
    document.getElementById(elemento.elemento).innerHTML = elemento.segundos;
    elemento.segundos--;
   }
   else
   {
    document.getElementById(elemento.elemento).innerHTML = "Cuenta finalizada";
    clearInterval(contador); 
   }
  }, 1000);
 });
```

```html
<span id=demo4></span><br>
<span id=demo5></span><br>
<span id=demo6></span><br>
```

Comment: También es buena solución porque `stop` está definido dentro de la IIFE. Mi +1.